# Remove duplicates after joining three different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, polarion

I'm working now on SQL query for Polarion widget, where I want get items with unresolved comments.
Unfortunately, I have a problem with joining three tables where one has optional empty/null.
In Polarion is a few different tables to contain **comments**, most of them has a **resolved** status. I'm using *WORKITEM, COMMENT, MODULECOMMENT* tables, because sometimes workitem has comment here, sometimes in another table.

Difference is one: when workitem has "normal" comment, then there is always FK key in *COMMENT* table, but not each workitem has a FK *MODULE* key ([table structure](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/database/FullDBSchema.pdf)).

In default widget, I can use SQL query with a one big limit:
**I can't replace whole *select* and *from*, because there is a static line: *SELECT WORKITEM.C_URI* and *FROM WORKITEM*, so I can only add something (I tried *DISTINCT ON*, but how can you see, I can't replace that line)**

Polarion has another problem too, each document has headings, texts etc. and each of this element is separate workitem with the same *FK_URI_MODULE* (and documents use *MODULECOMMENT* table).

I want remove duplicates from MODULECOMMENT (ignore situation where workitem.FK_URI_MODULE is empty/null, because it's normal state).

The best what I created, It's here (in this situation I replace *is null* to *is not null*, because It's return less items):

```
select workitem.c_uri, workitem.FK_URI_MODULE
from workitem 
left join COMMENT on COMMENT.FK_URI_WORKITEM = WORKITEM.C_URI 
left join MODULECOMMENT on MODULECOMMENT.FK_URI_MODULE = WORKITEM.FK_URI_MODULE 
where true
and workitem.fk_uri_project = 231 
and (comment.c_resolved is not null 
or modulecomment.c_resolved is not null);
```

and my results:

```
c_uri  | fk_uri_module
--------+---------------
   7952 |          7940
   7949 |          7940
   7953 |          7940
   7964 |          7940
 124141 |        124138
    609 |
   1347 |
    609 |
```

but I want get something like that:

```
c_uri  | fk_uri_module
--------+---------------
   7952 |          7940
 124141 |        124138
    609 |
   1347 |
    609 |
```

Comment: The last three records are also duplicates regarding the NULL value of the right column. These should be really ignored?

Comment: @S-Man, Yes, of course, I forgot to add this

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate the duplicates to begin with by not joining, but using an EXISTS condition:

```
select workitem.c_uri, workitem.fk_uri_module
from workitem 
where exists (select * 
              from comment 
                left join modulecomment on modulecomment.fk_uri_module = workitem.fk_uri_module 
              where comment.fk_uri_workitem = workitem.c_uri
                and (comment.c_resolved is not null 
                     or modulecomment.c_resolved is not null))
where workitem.fk_uri_project = 231
```

Comment: I have to change second where to "and" (before workitem.fk_uri_project = 231) and it doesn't work because there is any modulecomment records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` for this, which returns only the first record of a group:

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=00e0ff2449ab6cbb3411510955add23a)

```
select DISTINCT ON (workitem.FK_URI_MODULE) 

    workitem.c_uri, workitem.FK_URI_MODULE
from workitem 
left join COMMENT on COMMENT.FK_URI_WORKITEM = WORKITEM.C_URI 
left join MODULECOMMENT on MODULECOMMENT.FK_URI_MODULE = WORKITEM.FK_URI_MODULE 
where true
    and workitem.fk_uri_project = 231 
    and (comment.c_resolved is not null 
    or modulecomment.c_resolved is not null)
```

The interesting part is the `NULL` records. The query above returns only one of the `NULL` records, because `DISTINCT ON` also removes duplicates for `NULL`.

So, if you want to keep all `NULL` values, we need to treat the `NULL` records differently:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_uri_module)  -- 1
    *
FROM <your_query>
WHERE fk_uri_module IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT                              -- 2
    *
FROM <your_query>
WHERE fk_uri_module IS NULL
```

1. Apply `DISTINCT ON` on all records with non-`NULL` values
2. `UNION ALL` records with `NULL` afterwards

To avoid executing your entire query twice, you can move them into a CTE (`WITH` clause) and reference it later:

```
WITH my_result AS (
    -- <your_query>
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_uri_module)
    *
FROM my_result 
WHERE fk_uri_module IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
    *
FROM my_result 
WHERE fk_uri_module IS NULL
```

**Edit**:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=405568dbbddcdd2e9be766f3a696f845)

If you cannot use `DISTINCT ON`, a valid alternative for this is the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    select
        workitem.c_uri, workitem.FK_URI_MODULE,
    
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY workitem.FK_URI_MODULE)

    from workitem 
    left join COMMENT on COMMENT.FK_URI_WORKITEM = WORKITEM.C_URI 
    left join MODULECOMMENT on MODULECOMMENT.FK_URI_MODULE = WORKITEM.FK_URI_MODULE 
    where true
        and workitem.fk_uri_project = 231 
        and (comment.c_resolved is not null 
        or modulecomment.c_resolved is not null)
) s
WHERE row_number = 1
```

Comment: I can't use distinct on... I mentioned it

Comment: Added an alternative approach, but this only works if you are allowed to use subqueries. If that's not possible too, then your only chance is to avoid the duplicate joins before. Later remove is not possible with a way you like.

Comment: However, even if a solution does not fit completely your requirements, please don't forget to UPVOTE every answer which is helpful in a way (that can be: give a good hint, point out an approach or even show that your goal is not achievable). This honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your specific problem, it's their only reward and it motivates them to do so. :) We'd appreciate! :)